# Vue Route Params

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a single page of a product taken from a json list based on its id. I can't seem to get it up and running. Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong here? I Think im waaaay off.

Route:

```
{ path: '/product/:id',
  name: 'product',
  component: () => import('./views/Product.vue')
}
```

Product.vue:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <h1>Product: {{single.title}}</h1>
        <article></article>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { products } from '@/assets/data.json';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            products
        }
    },
    computed: {
      single() {
          return this.products.filter((product) => {return product.id == this.$route.params.id});
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How are you visiting the URL? I think it should be `path: '/product/:id'` with the extra slash, but it really depends on how you want the URL to be.

Comment: Ah yeah thats true... but I still don't get the data from the json file

Comment: if your problem is related to importing that json, you should probably rename the question, because (as far as I understand) it is not related to the vue router, or is it?

Comment: the json file works fine, so the problem is in the router or vue file.

Comment: you should check "this" variable is a window object or vue class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering the array is going to return an array. If you change `this.products.filter` to `this.products.find` you should get a single item.